# Выравнивание по ширине родительского блока

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, css-grid

Возможно ли сделать выравнивание типа justify-content: space-between; (flexbox/grid), но при этом чтобы по высоте автоматически выставлялся аналогичный отступ между элементами и при этом последние элементы выравнивались в порядке очереди а не растягивались по всей ширине.

Ps. Я знаю это возможно сделать выставив все отступы в ручную, но это долго а так получилось что подобные элементы мне приходится делать часто и было бы хорошо если бы можно было ускорить разработку и сделать более правильным такие элементы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Может то что вы искали

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0 auto;
    gap: 40px;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
}

.box {
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это уже лучше чем то как я делал до этого, но всё равно здесь отступ нужно выставлять через gap для того чтобы дочерние элементы вплотную прилегали к краям родительского и при этом был равный отступ как по ширине так и по высоте блока, я думал возможно есть способ чтобы это делалось автоматически.

Comment: @MAX GOLD , автоматический отступ строки нельзя задать в css, для этого надо скрипт писать с вычислениями